# Immutable property for mutable ivar using MRC

Tags: objective-c

Today I was at interview and was asked a question:

Generate setter and getter by hands for proper declaration using manual reference counting:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject 
{
     NSMutableArray* _array; 
}
@property (copy) NSArray* array;

@end
```

My answer was:

```
- (NSArray *)array 
{
     @syncronized (self)
     {
         return [_array copy];
     }  
}

- (void)setArray:(NSArray *)array 
{    
    @synchronized (self)    
    {    
      if (_array != array)
      {
         [_array release];
         _array = [array mutableCopy];
         [_array retain]
      }    
    } 
}
```

I never worked using MRC so not sure about correctness of an answer. Please help me to correct this code with description!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explicit getters/setters for @properties (MRC)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21802069/explicit-getters-setters-for-properties-mrc)

Comment: Thanks Josh, but I am asking about mutable/immutable ivar/property. So my question is about what do I need to set and get in this particular case

Comment: Also I don't know is there any sense or it is just the case for abstract test

Comment: It's been a long time since I used MRC, but I think you're leaking the copy in the getter (should be `return [[_array copy] autorelease]`)

Comment: Thanks @AaronBrager ! Question is also about different types of ivar and property. Can you comment this? Is it normal and really can be used in the daily practice?

Comment: It can be done. [How to declare an immutable property backed by a mutable type?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7710400)

Comment: @JoshCaswell All the examples in that answer *declare* immutability, but *actually* return the mutable instance variable.

Comment: @Alex It's normal to override getters and setters, so you might see code like this in a real app.  But there's no good reason to use MRC, so just transition the project to ARC after they hire you :)

Comment: Aaron, so is everything fine with return types and assigns, especially inside getter?

Comment: Copying is not always required, @AaronBrager. I believe modifying an object which was declared as immutable (return type of getter) because you know it's actually mutable should be considered an error. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3922549/ for some reasoning.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I guess that's fair.  In classes like this, I would typically maintain two instance variables (one mutable, one immutable), and recreate the immutable one when the mutable one changes.

Comment: (This allows me to mutate the contents of my internal variable on a different thread without worrying that some other class will modify it.)

Comment: @JoshCaswell, would you mind making a revision of the answer I've just posted?

Comment: @AaronBrager, would you mind making a revision of the answer I've just posted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am the author of [one of the linked topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21802069/explicit-getters-setters-for-properties-mrc?lq=1) and I think now I understand MRC enough to write this answer here:

1) You're obviously leaking the copy in the getter (see it also in the comments) - so it should be balanced by corresponding `autorelease` call.

Also note, that this **copy** inside your getter is done because of you need to return immutable object, not because of getters for @properties declared with **(copy)** require you to do so!

2) Your setter should not `retain` after `mutableCopy`, since mutableCopy already does +1 for you.

See the following quotes from [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH)

> Basic Memory Management Rules.
>
> You own any object you create
>
> You create an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy).

And

> Ownership Policy Is Implemented Using Retain Counts
>
> The ownership policy is implemented through reference counting—typically called “retain count” after the retain method. Each object has a retain count.
>
> When you create an object, it has a retain count of 1.

3) In my topic's comments @robmayoff shared the link to open source implementation of runtime: [reallySetProperty in objc-accessors.mm](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-551.1/runtime/Accessors.subproj/objc-accessors.mm) with the following reasoning behind it:

> The nonatomic retain and copy setters unfortunately have an unnecessary race condition. If, on thread 1, the setter releases _count, and on thread 2 the getter accesses _count before thread 1 has set _count = [count retain], thread 2 may access a deallocated object. Always store the new value in _count before releasing the old value. The real accessor in the Objective-C runtime does it correctly. See reallySetProperty in objc-accessors.mm. – rob mayoff

4) You example is also missing **dealloc** since you were to write it under MRC.

5) [IMO, maybe subjective] Since your setter is creating copies of array argument, you don't need to have this `if (_array != array)` check since the task of `(copy) setter` is, I believe, to produce **copies of what is passed**, so I think this is may be omitted.

Having these points in mind I would write your example like the following:

```
- (NSArray *)array 
{
     id array;
     @synchronized (self)
     {
         array = [_array copy];
     }
     return [array autorelease];  
} 

- (void)setArray:(NSArray *)array 
{    
    id oldValue;
    @synchronized (self)    
    {    
        oldValue = _array;
        _array = [array mutableCopy];
    } 
    [oldValue release];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [_array release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

---

In answer to your question in the comments:

> Is it normal and really can be used in the daily practice?

I would say, that it can be used in a daily practice with the following additional considerations:

1) You should move you ivar declaration into a private category `@interface SomeClass ()` be it inside your .m file or a private class extension.

2) You should make your getters/setters **nonatomic** since atomicity of this property is on your shoulders (you already do synchronized on your own in both setter and getter).

3) See also [the setup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20478826/598057) from linked topic which omits ivar and uses second @property declaration. In your case it would look like this:

```
// .h
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSArray *array;
@end

// .m or private class extension
@interface SomeClass()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *array;
@end

@implementation SomeClass
// and here your getters/setters
@end
```

This setup looks promising though I haven't really tested it for the case like yours.

---

P.S. Recently I did some research for this back-to-the-past Manual Reference Counting, let me share with you the following links which I found to be the best on this topic:

- [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1) (this is the MUST)
- [An In-depth Look At Manual Memory Management In Objective-C](http://tomdalling.com/blog/cocoa/an-in-depth-look-at-manual-memory-management-in-objective-c/) (this one too!)
- [What clang taught us about Objective-C properties](http://www.crashlytics.com/blog/what-clang-taught-us-about-objective-c-properties/)
- [Memory and thread-safe custom property methods](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/memory-and-thread-safe-custom-property.html)
- [Source code of objc runtime](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-551.1/runtime/Accessors.subproj/objc-accessors.mm).